# How to plot the FFT in Ltspice?

Tags: ltspice, fft

I'm new in Ltspice and I wonder how to plot the FFT of R1? I just failed to find such a tutorial and I'm sorry for such a stupid question. Thanks for your teaching!
[image]

Comment: FFT of R1 doesn't make much sense, it is just a resistance with no frequency dependence. FFT could be applied to voltage across R1 or current through it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the waveform for current flowing through R1.For getting the  FFT of the waveform,right click on the waveform,select the option view and then select FFT.

Then you van select which waveform you need.Please see the second image.

The FFT of resistor current is given in the last image.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your simulation has an additional 0 in the parameters for the AC source, so it's not the same impulse being applied to the asker's circuit. It should be (0 5 0 0 0 0.5m 1m), while you have (0 5 0 0 0 **0** 0.5m 1m).

Comment: Yes,my mistake,my intention is just to show how to find out FFT

Comment: Sure, you have done that quite well. But I think it might be worth changing if only to avoid confusing the asker when they try the same method and get graphs different than yours due to an easily-overlooked difference. Or worse (but much less likely): that they might notice the extra zero and end up thinking it's necessary for FFTs.

Comment: Sure,l will update it